# TFS: Pending Changes - Work Items screen closing code reviews prematurely

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have an odd TFS issue that no one else on my team seems to be experiencing. As far as I know I'm the only one on my team who likes using the Pending Changes windows so I'm assuming the issue is there.

After I have a code review approved I will navigate to the Work Items tab of the pending changes window. I will check the "Check-in Action" box and select "Associate". Immediately the code review goes to a closed state with a note in the history of the review saying I closed the review on behalf of the reviewer. I then cannot check-in my code since the review is now in a closed state. I get Check-In Validation, Unsupported check-in action for work item ####. If I refresh the view, the review I tried to associate with is now gone.

The only way for me to check-in is to re-open the review, assign it to myself, then set it to resolved state. It retains the association from before and now that the review is in the proper state I can finally check my code in. As you can imagine this routine is getting old. Any ideas?

Edit: VS2010 by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I got it figured out. You can select what query the Pending Change screen uses. My query was looking for code reviews not in closed state. Once the code review is associated it gets closed and drops out of the query results. The pending changes window won’t let you check-in if nothing is checked in the work-items screen even though the code review was associated.

I made a new query for the window to use that looks for code reviews I created that have been resolved in the past 7 days. I wish I could see just my open code reviews, but this seems to be the best solution given the restrictions of the screen.